# O que é o Google Mobile First Index?

Tags: seo

Há algum tempo o Google anunciou uma mudança na forma de indexação que irá fazer, mas que mudança é essa? O que vai mudar na vida do programador? Como será feita essa transição?

Comment: Já deixei uma reposta, mas ela é um tanto superficial, uma resposta mais completa é sempre bem vinda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de se desesperar tenha em mente algumas coisas.

Primeiro, por enquanto essa é uma prática da Google, não é uma regra geral, mesmo o Google representando 90% ou mais do mercado de busca no Brasil essa é uma prática da empresa e não da W3C, então não necessariamente tem a ver diretamente com os desenvolvedores, principalmente pra que desenvolve sistemas etc.

**Site Mobile (m) vs Mobile First**

Tenha em mente que aqui temos conceitos diferentes! O **Mobile First** seria a grosso modo um site desenvolvido primeiramente como foco no mobile, ele na verdade seria um site mobile que se adapta para telas grandes, e não um site feito para telas grande que se adapta para telas pequenas. Talvez na hora de desenvolver o ponto principal seja que as `medias queries` usam `min-width` e não `max-width` https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2015/03/como-escrever-seu-css-para-projetos-mobile-first/

```
/* este estilo aplica-se a partir de 0px até 900px */
body {
      background: red;
} 

/* este estilo aplica-se a partir de 900px em diante */
@media ( min-width: 900px ) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Já um **Site Mobile**, ou **Site M**, é um site "novo", ou seja não é um site único que se adapta a largura da tela, ele na verdade tem outra URL, outros arquivos .html, outros .css, etc... Apesar de um **Site M** poder ter conceitos de mobile first ele é um site diferente e seria algo como `m.example.com.br` e o outro `example.com.br`

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.example.com/">
```

---

**Recomendações da Google**

- Seu site para dispositivos móveis precisa apresentar o mesmo conteúdo do site para computador.
- Dados estruturados precisam estar presentes nas duas versões do seu site.
- Os metadados precisam estar presentes nas duas versões do site.
- Verifique as duas versões do seu site no **Search Console** para garantir que você tenha acesso aos dados e às mensagens de ambas.
- Verifique os links URLs separados.
- Verifique se as diretivas do `robots.txt`
- Verifique se você tem os elementos do link `rel=canonical` e `rel=alternate` corretos

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing

---

**SEO**

Veja o que o Google diz:

> No Google, há uma preferência pelo conteúdo otimizado para dispositivos móveis no processo de indexação.

Então do ponto de vista do SEO no Google isso implica que se seus concorrentes já possuírem a versão mobile, eles poderão ficar na sua frente. Ou seja o Google tende a dar preferencia a retornar em suas buscas resultados de Sites do tipo M.

Isso não necessariamente quer dizer que o seu site único Responsivo vai deixar de ser indexado pelo *crawler* deles, apenas quer dizer que ele pode melhorar o rankeamente de Sites M nos resultados de pesquisa. Inclusive a **SERP** pode variar dependendo se a pesquisa foi feita de um dispositivo Mobile ou Desktop. SERP: https://www.significados.com.br/serp/

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing

---

**Questionamento**

Ponto a se pensar...Para que ter dois site se podemos ter apenas um Site M, porém que se adapte para o Desktop, tendo apenas uma URL `m.example.com.br`. Nesse senário como ficaria a validação do *bot* da Google? Como ficaria a resultado da **SERP** se o site apenas tiver uma Versão `M`?

Answer (score 1):

Em relação a web design, já existe há um bom tempo a ideia de mobile first para criação do layout e design, isso porque, hoje, as páginas são acessadas maioritariamente por dispositivos móveis, então cria primeiro o site para mobile e, depois, desktop

Se isso já existe na criação do site, porque não na sua indexação seria diferente? Basicamente, o Mobile First Index é indexar as páginas web pela sua versão mobile. Essa mudança será gradual, já há sites que estão sendo indexados dessa forma, futuramente todos passaram por isso, porém ainda falta muito para isso acontecer, não quer dizer que não deva se preocupar, é importante já ficar atento a essas mudanças e colocar elas em prática

Um ponto importante é a página mobile ser o mais completo possível, diversos sites possuem uma versão desktop completa e a mobile com conteúdo enxuto, o que pode prejudicar a indexação

https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing

https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/google-mobile-first-index/amp/